# Mysql's internal mysql database in replication

Tags: mysql, replication, security

I searched around but the word game seems to delude any valid result and could not find anything relevant.

Mysql (the RDBMS) has an internal database named *mysql*, this database has information about the users and as far as I know, information and settings about the server running the RDBMS.

### Background Info

In our set up we have a few MySQL 5.5 servers and one test MySQL 5.6 server.

Replication is set up so that the 5.6 is a slave of one of the 5.5

### Incident

This week the replication to the 5.6 stopped working, when doing a `show slave status` this error was reported:

```
Error: Error Column count doesnt match value count at row 1 on query. 
Default database: mysql. 
Query: INSERT INTO tmp_user VALUES (localhost,root,,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,,,,,0,0,0,0,,)
```

When I checked, the `mysql` database did not have a `tmp_user` table, however the error is that the column count doesnt match, what I expected was for the error to be that the table did not exist (Error 1146).

Another conclusion that I gathered from this situation is that we are replicating the database `mysql`.

### Questions

1. Is there any concern/benefit in replicating the `mysql` database?
2. Do you see this scenario as an injection attack? or a security concern?
   (Perhaps I am missing a scenario where creating/populating/deleting a tmp_user table is
   normal)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, what the heck is `tmp_user`?  This smells like an attack.  And I suspect it was successful.  He probably already got in -- all he had to do was to try different flavors of the `INSERT` based on different versions.  The one successful insert would suffice.  Then he `RENAMEs` tables, does damage, rename tables back, `DROPs` evidence of his naughtiness, and vanishes.  That insert looks like he could log in with all permissions and no password.  Once he has `SUPER` he can do nasties like read all files (including /etc/passwd) on your system.  Who knows what other goodies he found on your machine.  Nice trick.

How did he get this far?

- Port 3306 is not firewalled from people *outside* your building.
- some non-root mysql 'user' has too much access to the `mysql` database.  Possibly you simply did `GRANT ALL ON *.* to ...` for each application 'user'?  Instead, use `ON dbname.*`; that would at least prevent messing around in `mysql`.
- Perhaps SQL injection allowed `CREATE TABLE mysql.tmp_user ...` to be performed from your externally facing UI.  Escape all user-provided strings.  Don't allow multiple statements to be executed in a single command.

Replicating the `mysql` database has benefits and drawbacks, especially between different versions.

- (plus) GRANTs, etc, are propagated to the slaves
- (minus) the structure of `mysql` tables sometimes changes between major (eg, 5.5 to 5.6) versions, thereby disallowing direct manipulation of `mysql` tables.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Rick more information has come to light since then, the queries look like the ones run by the `mysql_install_db` script, but no one in the team executed that script, so we are still wondering why -if it was indeed this script- was it triggered. We are bringing in a security company to help us figure it out. Thanks again Rick!

Comment: Please report back if it was a valid script.  Or if it was an attack, especially if it was allowed by something I did not mention.  "We" all need to protect ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to 2) question - Most probably you had some minor version upgrade for your master 5.5 MySQL server. There is a bug for 5.0 - [Bug #50876](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50876) and according to my experience, the same bug exists in 5.5